# How to Add Values to a Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, hash

I have done much research on this topic, but in every circumstance I attempt, the values appear to be replaced in the hash. After the person opts to enter a new ID, I would like the next person's name and age to be added to the hash. Could someone explain to me why the keys and values are being replaced?

```
class Person
  def initialize(name, age)
    if name != nil || age != nil
      if @people != nil
        @people[name.__id__] = age.__id__
      else
        @people = {name => age}
      end
    else
      puts "Invalid credentials."
    end
  end

  attr_reader :people
end

class MainInit
  def initialize()
    options = ["y", "yes", "n", "no"]
    choice = "y"
    while choice.downcase == "y" || choice.downcase == "yes"
      p "Enter Name:"
      inputname = gets.chomp
      p inputname

      p "Enter Age:"
      inputage = gets.chomp
      p inputage

      person = Person.new(inputname, inputage)
      p person.people

      p "Enter another ID?"
      choice = gets.chomp
      until options.include? choice.downcase
        p "Invalid Choice"
        p "Enter another ID?"
        choice = gets.chomp
      end
    end
  end
end

MainInit.new
```

Comment: `@people` is an instance variable, so there is one for each instance.  Each one contains only a single key/value pair.  I'm guessing you want to store the names and ages associated with all the instance variables in `@people`. If so, you need to make `@people` a class instance variable (or use a class variable, like @@people).

Comment: You need to restructure your classes since you want to keep state, you need to change `attr_reader :people` to `attr_accessor :people` so you can alter the structure of the people hash, I also don't think your use of `__id__` is right or necessary, and move all the logic in the initialize method of `MainInit` into another method, leaving only `@people = Person.new(nil, nil)` in it, then you can call the new method you created e.g `MainInit.new.new_method` instead of `MainInit.new` at the end of your script

Comment: I'll have another answer for you shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason the key-value pairs are being replaced is this:

The statement in your `initialize` method

```
if @people != nil
```

will always evaluate to `false`.  `initialize` is called when you create a new object, so by default `@people` has not been defined or set yet, so each time you call

```
 person = Person.new(inputname, inputage)
```

it creates a new `Person` rather than adding the new person to an exiting Hash (which is what I think you are trying to do).

It *might* work if you make `people` a class variable (`@@people`),  but it seems like you just want to create a Hash in your main program and then add the new entries in there.

So something like this

```
people = Hash.new # Or even just people = {}
```

Then when you have a new name / age entry to add

```
people[name] = age
```

I have not tried it, but I think your entire program should be reduced to something like this:

```
people = Hash.new
options = ["y", "yes", "n", "no"]
    choice = "y"
    while choice.downcase == "y" || choice.downcase == "yes"
      p "Enter Name:"
      inputname = gets.chomp
      p inputname

      p "Enter Age:"
      inputage = gets.chomp
      p inputage

      #person = Person.new(inputname, inputage)
      people[inputname] = inputage
      person = people[inputname]
      p person.people

      p "Enter another ID?"
      choice = gets.chomp
      until options.include? choice.downcase
        p "Invalid Choice"
        p "Enter another ID?"
        choice = gets.chomp
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me both explain why you are having the problem you describe and also offer some suggestions for how you might change your code.

**`class Person`**

In class `Person`, you need to save your list of persons at the class level, which means the use of either a class instance variable (e.g., `@people`) or a class variable (e.g., `@@people`).  I am with the majority of Rubiests in prefering the former.  (The reasons are beyond the scope of this answer, but you will find a lot written on the subject by simply Googling, "Ruby 'class instance variables' versus 'class variables'".  The inner quotes--the only ones you enter--help narrow the search.)

To define a class instance variable, @people, we just enter it as follows:

```
class Person
  @people = {}
  class << self
    attr_accessor :people
  end
  def initialize(name, age)
    self.class.people[name] = age
  end
end
```

The `@` means it is an instance variable.  As soon as Ruby reads `class Person`, it sets `self` to `Person`.  It then reads `@people = {}` and makes that an instance variable of `Person`.  By contrast, if you were to initialize `@person` within, say, an `initialize` method, `self` would at that time be an instance of `Person`, so `@person` would be a normal instance variable.  (Aside: we could have both a class instance variable `@person` and an instance variable `@person`, and Ruby would treat them as differently as it would `@night` and `@day`.)

In order for objects to access `@people` we define an accessor.  If we just entered `attr_accessor :person`, Ruby would create an accessor for a regular instance variable `@person`.  Instead we enter `class << self`, which directs Ruby to associate what follows, until `end` is reached, with the class.

Each time a new instance of Person is created, for a given `name` and `age`,

```
self.class.people[name] = age
```

adds an element to the hash @person, since `self.class` is `Person` and `people` is the accessor.

Now look at the class `MainInit`

**class `MainInit`**

```
class MainInit
  def initialize
    loop do
      name = nil
      loop do
        print 'Enter Name: '
        name = gets.strip
        break unless name.empty?
      end  
      puts "name is #{name}"
      age = nil
      loop do
        print 'Enter Age: '
        age = gets.strip
        case age
        when /^\d+$/ && ('10'..'120')
          break
        else
          puts 'age must be between 10 and 120'
        end  
      end  
      puts "age is #{age}"
      person = Person.new(name, age)
      puts "people is now #{Person.people}"
      loop do
        print "Enter another ID? "
        case gets.chomp.downcase
        when 'n', 'no'
          return
        when 'y', 'yes'
          break
        else
          puts 'Invalid choice'
        end  
      end
    end
  end  
end
```

*`loop do...end`*

You see that in several places I have used `loop do...end` with `break` to exit a loop.  I'm a big fan of this construct, as compared to loop `while...` or or `until...`, in part because it avoids the need to enter a starting condition to get into the loop and then repeat the same condition withing the loop.  I also just think it looks cleaner.

Any variables created within the loop cease to exist when you leave the loop, so if you want a variable's value (e.g., `name` and `age`), you must reference the variable outside of the beginning of the loops.  That is why (and the only reason) I have `name = nil` and `age = nil`.  It didn't have to be `nil`; I could have initialized them to anything.

*Use of `case` statement*

The loop for getting age uses this case statement:

```
case age
when /^\d+$/ && ('10'..'120')
  ...
end
```

This requires some explanation.  The `case` statement uses [String#===](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D), rather than [String#==](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-3D-3D) to obtain truthy values.  Therefore `when /^\d+$/` is equivalent to:

```
/^\d+$/ === age
```

which is the same as

```
/^\d+$/ =~ age
```

The regex simply ensures that all characters of age are digits (e.g., "39).

Similarly,

```
('10'..'120') === age
```

is the same as

```
('10'..'120').cover?(age)
```

**Odds and Ends**

I used `String#strip` in place of `String#chomp`.  Both remove ending newline characters, but `strip` also removes spaces the user may have entered at the beginning or end of the input string.

For strings, I mostly used single quotes, but double-quotes are needed for string interpolation.  For example, I initially wrote `puts 'name is #{name}'`.  That printed `name is #{name}`.  After changing that to `puts "name is #{name}"`, it correctly printed `name is Debra`.

**Example**

```
MainInit.new
Enter Name: Debra       
name is Debra
Enter Age: 29
age is 29
people is now {"Debra"=>"29"}
Enter another ID? y
Enter Name: Billy-Bob
name is Billy-Bob
Enter Age: 58
age is 58
people is now {"Debra"=>"29", "Billy-Bob"=>"58"}
Enter another ID? u
Invalid choice
Enter another ID? n
```